# Predicting output using a recursion tree

Tags: java, recursion

1. I have this method and I want to be able to predict the output of this recursive method
2. using a recursion tree, anyone have an idea of what this would look like?

Code:

```
 public static void main(String[ ] args) {
     f(5, 2); }

 public static void f(int x, int y) {
     if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
         f(y - 1, x - 2);
         f(x - 2, y);
         System.out.print((x + y) + " ");
         f(x - 3, y - 1);
         System.out.print((x - y) + " ");
     }      
  }
```

Comment: Ask your instructor, or reread the chapter. I can think of many ways to draw something I'd call a "recursion tree", but it's unlikely that any of them will exactly match what you've been asked to turn in.

Answer (score 0):

Start substituting the calls to `f` with the actual code in `f`. Try it in Notepad or whatever program that has copy-paste. Fill in `x` and `y` with their appropriate values. When the if-statement is false, you can leave out its contents, otherwise you can keep substituting forever.

You'll see why we call it a recursion tree once you've done two or three of these substitutions. How to draw this recursion tree is up to you. Usually we write the name of the method that is called in every node of the tree, together with the arguments to the call.